# Using CTCall API when running background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Can a VOIP app be able to get the call status ( Using CTCall API )of a call being made from native iPhone's dialer.

Reason behind the above question is, a voip app can be running in the background, so i think is it possible to track the call status of the call made from native iPhone dialer?

Thanks for any insights